# Xpath issue with simple importXML query

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The following is not returning any data in a Google spreadsheet, even though the //h1 xpath query verifies OK using Chrome's XPath Helper extension:

```
=importXML("http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/1118358708","//h1")
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That's importXML("http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/1118358708","//h1"). Not sure why importXML("http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118358708","//h1") is displayed.

Comment: Very strange -- the importxml works fine for the amazon.co.uk site ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture element using ImportXML with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908176/capture-element-using-importxml-with-xpath)

Answer (score 1):

Google bots respect the robots.txt file, which includes:

```
Disallow: /gp/offer-listing/
```