# Capture element using ImportXML with XPath

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the following information via Google Sheets from the page as an example [here](https://lubematch.shell.com/it/it/equipment/motorcycles/yamaha/yzf_r6_2cx_motorcycles_EFt8Plr5e).

I have to retrieve these two items circled in red as in the attached screenshot of scrape data interest.

[image: screenshot of scrape data interest]

I've tried this, but it does not work (in A1 there is the link, and B1 the formula):

```
=IMPORTXML(A1;"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1])

=IMPORTXML(A1;"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3])
```

Is there anyone who can please help me?

Comment: If the content isn't on the source code of the page, IMPORTXML could not read it.

Answer (score 2):

Their robots.txt file:

```
User-Agent: *  
Disallow: /
```

[The "User-agent: *" means this section applies to all robots. The "Disallow: /" tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Information required could be extracted with Excel, From Web.