# Import data from LinkedIn URL to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, linkedin-api, google-sheets-formula

We have set up a small organic content strategy on LinkedIn. We will say that we interviewed 20 people and each posted the video in organic on his LinkedIn account.

Is it possible to automatically retrieve the number of likes, comments and views of each video and insert the data in Google Sheets in the cell proper to each person?

Is it possible to taff with supermetrics? Or do you have tips/advice?

I've tried with `importxml` and `importhtml;list`

```
=IMPORTXML("www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPost:6535053243351867393/";"//*[@class='social-details-social-counts__item']") =IMPORTHTML("https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPost:6535053243351867393/";"list";1)
```

Neither of these two work.

I get the error message:

> "Could not fetch URL"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47908176/1595451

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** The answer is "NO".

LinkedIn is not keen to share data (it is owned by Microsoft). For example, their robots.txt file starts:

> ```
>  # Notice: The use of robots or other automated means to access LinkedIn without
>  # the express permission of LinkedIn is strictly prohibited.
>  # See https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement.
>  # LinkedIn may, in its discretion, permit certain automated access to certain LinkedIn pages,
>  # for the limited purpose of including content in approved publicly available search engines.
>  # If you would like to apply for permission to crawl LinkedIn, please email whitelist-crawl@linkedin.com.
>  # Any and all permitted crawling of LinkedIn is subject to LinkedIn's Crawling Terms and Conditions.
>  # See http://www.linkedin.com/legal/crawling-terms.
> ```

and under `User-agent: Googlebot`:

```
Disallow: /feed/update/
```